# Why my $PATH is not inherited by the invoked bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, aix, path, tcsh

I work on an AIX system where I have no administrator privileges. It has several shells installed, default being `tcsh`. I am not allowed to change the login shell. Usually I start my session from `exec bash`. The problem is that I do not inherit the `$PATH` I had in `tsch`. The first strange thing is that some of the entries in my `$PATH` are duplicated, when I do `exec bash`.  Another strange thing is that when I do `exec bash --norc` and then `source .bashrc` everything is fine -- I get the path from tcsh and some additions from my `.bashrc`.

I have tried commenting out my `.bashrc` enirely, but it gave no result -- I still do not get the `$PATH` from `tcsh`. It seems that the system wide /etc/profile is manipulating my `$PATH`. I tried running `exec bash --noprofile`, but I still see the changes, that are introduced by `/etc/profile` script (which I have no control over).

So in the end perhaps someone spotted a flaw in my investigation and can tell me how to invoke bash with inhereted `$PATH` or can suggest a way to do it without reading the global config scripts?

(I have posted this question on superuser as well, I am not sure if it is ok, to duplicate questions, but I got no answer there, so what a heck...)

Comment: No, it is generally not ok to *cross post* - this makes moderators' work harder.

Comment: It just seems this stackexchange site is less crowded, than superuser.com

Comment: [Do not crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). The right thing to do to move your question from [su] to here would have been to flag a moderator asking for the question to be migrated (but it's too late now).

Comment: Don't define `PATH` in `~/.bashrc`; see [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980). Run `exec bash -x` to see what's going on when you start bash; post the trace here.

Answer (score 1):

If doing `source .bashrc` gives you the environment you want, then what you are missing is an interactive login shell. To make `bash` work in that way, simply run `exec bash --login` or short `exec bash -l`.

Comment: Didn't do anything new. I login to my box, do some changes to my $PATH, then do exec bash --login and loose the my $PATH that was available in tcsh.

Comment: Hm, so is it different from what you get after doing `exec bash --norc` + `source .bashrc` (as you've described)?

Comment: How about the same thing without `exec`? (that is, run just `bash -l`)

Comment: `exec bash --norc` + `source .bashrc` is different from `exec bash --login` and `exec bash --noprofile`. Leaving `exec` out does not change anything. The other environment variables are not changed. If I `setenv v hi` in tcsh, then I can see it when I do `echo $v` in bash whichever way it was invoked it. So it is something that manipulates the environment. In man bash (as far as I read) several scripts are listed as a startup sequence (for a login shell however): /etc/profile,  ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  ~/.profile. Out of those only /etc/profile exists on my system.

Comment: *"(...) /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile. Out of those only /etc/profile exists on my system."* - **This means you need to create `~/.bash_profile`** and put **`[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`** in it. If *that* doesn't solve it, I will have to delete my answer as irrelevant.

Comment: Consider also adding the information from your last comment to the main description in your question; I believe it is highly relevant to the problem.